# textFieldShouldEndEditing not called when user taps Done Button in UIKeyboard

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uikeyboard, uitextfielddelegate

I do validation of UITextField in `textfieldShouldEndEditing` delegate method, so every time I change the UITextfield being edited the method is called and the validation is performed.

The return button of the keyboard is configured as Done button. When it is pressed I process the input, but the  `textfieldShouldEndEditing` of the last edited UItextField is never called before, so it is not validated.

This seems strange to me since the normal behavior is the user just hitting done button after entering the last character in the field, but this does not trigger the `textFieldShouldEndEditing`method.

To take on this I have to force validation again in the `textfieldShouldReturn` method.

Maybe I'm missing some point since I can't find the logic in this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the problem.

I have to resignFirstResponder in `textfieldShouldReturn`and then the `textfieldShouldEndEditing`is called after.

This are my methods. I have two UITextFields. `self.username`is an IBOutlet to one of them with return button configured as NEXT. `self.password`is other IBOutlet pointing to a UITextField with Done return Button.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.userName) {
        return [self validateUserName:textField.text];

    }



    if (textField == self.password) {
        return [self validatePassword:textField.text];

    }

    //No hay errores de validación
    return YES;    
}


-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //In userName return is Next
    //In password return is Done

    if (textField == self.userName) {
        [self.password becomeFirstResponder];
    } 
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;    
}
```